# How to cite multiple sentences from the same book in the Vancouver system?

Tags: citations, vancouver-system

I've written a few paragraphs and in them I cited three short sentences from the same book, same chapter and marked them as ...(1)...(2)...(3).... My endnotes now look like this:

```
(1) Author1, ..., Author 5, Book name (3rd ed.), Publisher, City, Year
(2) Author1, ..., Author 5, Book name (3rd ed.), Publisher, City, Year
(3) Author1, ..., Author 5, Book name (3rd ed.), Publisher, City, Year
```

And that looks ugly. Same book with 5 authors repeated three times. Is there any guideline about multiple quotations from the same book when using the Vancouver style?

Comment: I tried to add vancouver tag but I'm not allowed. Can somebody add this tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add details like the page numbers, then several end notes are useful. (2) and (3) would only contain an ibidem (or ibid.) and the differing page numbers.

But as I know Vancouver does not care about page numbers that much (and you are not showing them), also Latin abbreviations are not used with this system. Therefore only one end note should be sufficient. Why don't you use just ...(1)...(1)...(1) in your text, or ...(1)...(ibid.)...(ibid.)? Do you need for each citation one end note?

Comment: I didn't see (1)...(1)...(1) or (ibid.) style in any guideline so I wasn't sure. Using ibid as keyword, I've found that (1)...(1)...(1) is preferred way in Vancouver system. Thanks for your help.