# Correct usage/explanation of ibid in referencing

Tags: citations, footnotes

My girlfriend was advised to use `Ibid` in her assignment's citations to `help reduce the word count` (I pointed out that references are usually not part of the count, but regardless); but she couldn't grasp the concept or why `Ibid` would be used.

```
I explained that it would typically be used when writing footnotes1 and that 
the material you were referencing2 is the same, and used in more than one place3.


[1] Anon, Lorem Ipsum (SE Publishing, 1999), p23
[2] Ibid.
[3] Ibid., p30
```

My argument was that you would save redundancy, by not having to write out the author name/title again, as well as provide a logical way of keeping footnotes numbered (1,2,3..) rather than (1,1,1,2) if the same work was cited more than once.

Is my understanding correct? Could anyone clarify and explain it in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. "ibid" is short for "[ibidem](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ibidem)", meaning "in the same place". It is used to not repeat the same title again and again.

Also have a look at this question:
[Vancouver system, citing multiple sentences from the same book](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/vancouver-system-citing-multiple-sentences-from-the-same-book)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, though.  "ibid" is considered, at least in some circles, to be old-fashioned, even archaic.  What citation style is your girlfriend using?

ETA: Unless someone *in authority* advised her to use it, I don't think she should.  You're using it as correctly as possible, but it's still not likely to be a popular choice in this day and age.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment, Kate. I almost flagged it before I saw that it was you. Could you elaborate the alternatives to make it an answer? (To your concern: I have linked to the Vancouver question exactly for the same reason. On the other hand he said she was advised to do it.)

Comment: Not long ago, at least in my main discipline (music), _Ibid._ was not only in use, but required in situations where it could be used.  I recall _Idem._ being out of favor and not to be used at all.  The style is basically Turabian/Chicago.  I don't have my manual handy, but do you have a source?

Comment: I don't know Chicago all that well, so maybe ibid survives there.  I was thinking of MLA and APA. In terms of a source - it's a bit tricky, because there's more of an absence of mentions, rather than a specific ban.  They both use in-text citations, which are already largely abbreviated, so I guess maybe they just don't see the need to go that little bit shorter?